# How to activate a button (CButton) located in a disabled window (CWnd)?

Tags: mfc, window, cwnd, cbutton

I have this code :

```
m_pBtnCom = new CButton();
m_pBtnCom->Create(_T("Push"), WS_CHILD|WS_VISIBLE|BS_PUSHBUTTON|BS_TEXT|BS_VCENTER|BS_CENTER, rc, this, BTN_CMT);
```

**Where:**

- `this` = my derived `CWnd` class
- `rc`   = `CRect` button position
- `BTN_CMT` = button id

**Current context:**
If I disable the parent `CWnd` by calling `EnableWindow(FALSE)`, even if I call the function `EnableWindow(TRUE)` on the button (`m_pBtnCom->EnableWindow(TRUE)`), the latter remains disabled; Therefore, nothing works on it: click, tooltip, ...
I tried to remove `WS_CHILD`, without success

**Question:**
Is it possible to activate the button when the window (argument **`this`** in my code) is disabled?

Comment: This sounds like you are trying to solve a different problem altogether. Are you perhaps trying to create a window whose child windows can be interacted with, but leaves the parent window inactive?

Comment: @IInspectable I want to disable the window that contains my button and make ONE exception for ONE button (m_pBtnCom) to be able to : click, see tooltip, ...

Comment: Yes, child window can't be independently enabled when parent window is disabled. Don't remove `WS_CHILD` flag from child window. You might consider using `GetWindow(GW_CHILD)` and `while ... GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT)` to disable/enable each child. You also have to handle dialog's close button.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani Thanks. that's what I was trying to avoid, but since I have no choice, I have to do it.

Comment: @BarmakShemirani suggestion is simple enough. 

Comment: Why not add your final code as an answer?

Comment: Hi @AndrewTruckle, good idea, added it

Answer (score 1):

Child window can't be independently enabled when parent window is disabled. You can instead enable all children, then go back and enable the particular button.

Note, if you have `IDCANCEL` button, and you disable it, then the dialog's close button is not functioning either and it gets confusing. You may want to avoid disabling the cancel button and override `OnCancel`

```
void CMyDialog::enable_children(bool enable)
{
    auto wnd = GetWindow(GW_CHILD);
    while (wnd)
    {
        wnd->EnableWindow(enable);
        wnd = wnd->GetWindow(GW_HWNDNEXT);
    }
}

BOOL CMyDialog::OnInitDialog()
{
    CDialog::OnInitDialog();
    enable_children(FALSE);
    
    //re-enable one button
    if(GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)) GetDlgItem(IDCANCEL)->EnableWindow(TRUE);
    return TRUE;
}

void OnCancel()
{
    MessageBox(L"cancel...");
    CDialog::OnCancel();
}
```